# Oxyplot division color change

Tags: oxyplot

Does anyone know how to change the color of the division markers on an oxyplot? I can't seem to find that specific property anywhere.  Here is the code I am using to produce the plot below.  As you can see the division markers are black.  Would really like to change their color.  Thanks.

```
 <oxy:Plot PlotAreaBorderColor="White"  Background="#242426" TextColor="White" Margin="5" Title="X and Y FPOS" TitleFontSize="12" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding XYData}"/>
    </oxy:Plot>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property you are looking for is `TicklineColor`. You have to do it in both axes:

**Effect:**

[image: Effect acquired]

**Code:**

```
<oxy:Plot>
...
    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" TicklineColor="White" />
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" TicklineColor="White" />    
    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Comment: Awesome. What version added this feature? Because when I try to use it I get the error.

Comment: My current oxyplot version is 2014.1.546.0

Answer (score 2):

I think, in this moment it is impossible to set color of markers. But, perhaps, you will approach the option of using PlotAreaBackground.

Example:

.xaml:

```
<oxy:Plot PlotAreaBorderColor="Green"  Background="DarkGreen" 
          PlotAreaBackground="#242426" TextColor="White" 
          Title="X and Y FPOS" TitleFontSize="12" 
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding XYData}" Color="Yellow"/>
</oxy:Plot>
```

.fs:

```
type MainViewModel() = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()  

    let data = [0.0..0.1..50.0] |> List.mapi(fun i x -> DataPoint(float i, cos x))
    member self.XYData with get() = data
```

Screenshot:

[image: PlotAreaBackground]